# Reset managed object context does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, restore, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a main managed object context (MOC) in the UI thread which is usually updated by worker threads. Works fine!

However, I have one view where I create another MOC (called editingMOC) in the UI thread. I read myObject via objectID in editingMOC. Afterwards I do some modifications on the object `myObject` in the editingMOC. If the user hits `cancel`, the following happens:

```
[self.editingMOC reset];

myObjectEdit = [self.editingMOC existingObjectWithID:myObject.objectID error:NULL];
```

Shouldn't that restore `myObjectEdit` to it's state as it was before? I *did not* call save. Nevertheless `myObjectEdit` has still my changes. Any idea what might be wrong?

Thank you!

---

Update:

Apparently the refresh of `myObjectEdit` is correct (Thanks Mark Adams). I tracked it down to this weird behaivor:

```
// RESET VALUE - OK
NSLog(@"%@", myEditObject);

self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

// OLD VALUE AGAIN - WRONG
NSLog(@"%@", myEditObject);
```

I haven't changed anything regarding to `userInteractionEnabled`. Does this method have any side effects not stated in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` to your `NSManagedObjectContext`. Pass in your `NSManagedObject` subclass and pass `NO` to `mergeChanges:`. This turns the object back into a fault and discards any changes since it was last fetched from a persistent store. In this case, the object has never been in a store, so it is completely discarded.

```
[self.editingMOC refreshObject:myObject mergeChanges:NO];
```

[NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference - `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJFCECB)

***Edit***: It seems from your question that you may be passing objects around between threads. In that case, be sure to create the object by objectID instead of referencing the object across threads. I'm assuming you already know this though...

Comment: Did I get your right? I call this and it is still not working: [self.editingMOC reset];

myObjectEdit = [self.editingMOC existingObjectWithID:myObject.objectID error:NULL];
[self.editingMOC refreshObject:myObjectEdit mergeChanges:NO];

Comment: Sending `reset` is causing the MOC to forget all of its objects but it doesn't necessarily invalidate existing objects. What happens if you reset after refreshing the object?

Comment: Then I get: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'The NSManagedObject with ID:....> has been invalidated.'

Comment: So refreshObject:mergeChanges: is doing what we expect. The -reset message is unnecessary.

Comment: OK I found it. You have to disable any caching of the managed object context with: "moc.stalenessInterval = 0.0;". Can you edit your answer accordingly? Thanks!